# Embedding forms with ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one form that I need to use with one method and one controller. Then, inside of it, I need to add a form that pulls from a completely different method in a different controller.

The first form starts with this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "post-box-form",   enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

The second form starts with this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("AddGroupAttachment", "Group", new { id = Model.ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

I'm getting a runtime exception that says "cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

I was wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can't nest forms.

Docs: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html

> Note you are not allowed to nest FORM elements!

Move your inner form to somewhere outside of your main form.  Shouldn't have any issues doing that since you're still just accessing your `Model` variable in the declaration.